# How to use \xpatchcmd with a macro containing \@

Tags: xpatch

I have the following reduced example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\foo{Foo}
\def\bar{Bar}

\def\mycommandA{i.e.\ \foo{}}
\def\mycommandB{i.e.\@ \foo{}}

\tracingpatches

\begin{document}

\xpatchcmd{\mycommandA}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mycommandB}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}

\mycommandA

\mycommandB

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to use `\@` rather than `\` , but the above only patches `\mycommandA` successfully, and for `\mycommandB` I get:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 16
[debug] analyzing '\mycommandB'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] -- macro cannot be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -> the macro may have been defined under a category
[debug]    code regime different from the current one
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain special control
[debug]    sequence tokens formed with \csname...\endcsname;
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain carriage return,
[debug]    newline, or similar characters
```

Is there a way to use `\xpatchcmd` such that it works with `\@`?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `etoolbox` (of which `xpatch` is a wrapper for adding extended functionality) doesn't allow that: since most of the commands one needs to patch contain `@` in command names, it does a good deal of juggling in order to be able to work.

You can do it with `regexpatch`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\def\foo{Foo}
\def\bar{Bar}

\def\mycommandA{i.e.\ \foo{}}
\def\mycommandB{i.e.\@ \foo{}}

\tracingxpatches

\begin{document}

\xpatchcmd{\mycommandA}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mycommandB}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}

\mycommandA

\mycommandB

\end{document}
```

<sub>A new release of `regexpatch` is on its way to CTAN for fixing a glitch.</sub>

[image]

The relevant messages from `\tracingxpatches`:

```
xpatch message
 `\mycommandA' is not especially defined
xpatch message
 Macro`\mycommandA' is patchable
xpatch message
 `\mycommandB' is not especially defined
xpatch message
 Macro`\mycommandB' is patchable
```

Comment: Hm, where this gets awkward is that I'm trying to patch in @-commands, so need the patch itself now to be inside \makeatletter due to regexpatch's differing requirements. Is there a way I can make that work?

Comment: @jrtc27 There's no way to manage `@` in two different incarnations.

Comment: Hm, I naively assumed there would be a way to patch based on tokens ie post category code-based parsing and thus you could mix and match `@` interpretations when patching. It's a bit ugly but I guess I can work around it by using `\wrapper{i.e.}` to hide the `\@` from `\xpatchcmd`.

Answer (score 3):

Surrounding the definition of `\mycommandB` with `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is sufficient to make the `\xpatchcmd` work.  It is unclear from your question whether this is suitable for your application, where you may or may not be defining the commands you wish to later patch.

Also, I replaced a hard space with `\@sptoken`, to avoid it getting absorbed during the patch.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\foo{Foo}
\def\bar{Bar}

\def\mycommandA{i.e.\ \foo{}}
\makeatletter
\def\mycommandB{i.e.\@\@sptoken\foo{}}
\makeatother

\tracingpatches

\begin{document}

\xpatchcmd{\mycommandA}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mycommandB}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}

\mycommandA

\mycommandB

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, if one omitted the `\@` from my approach, such that

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycommandB{i.e.\@sptoken\foo{}}
\makeatother
\xpatchcmd{\mycommandB}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}

\mycommandB
```

One would find the space added would be the larger end-of-sentence spacing, rather than the interword spacing.

Another MWE that demonstrates these concepts would be as follows, where `\mycommandC` uses neither `\`  nor `\@`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\foo{Foo}
\def\bar{Bar}

\def\mycommandA#1{#1\ \foo{}}
\makeatletter
\def\mycommandB#1{#1\@\@sptoken\foo{}}
\makeatother
\def\mycommandC#1{#1 \foo{}}

\begin{document}

\mycommandA{x.}

\mycommandB{x.}

\mycommandC{x.}

\xpatchcmd{\mycommandA}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mycommandB}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mycommandC}{\foo}{\bar}{}{}

\mycommandA{x.}

\mycommandB{x.}

\mycommandC{x.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The real situation is far more complex. Essentially I'm trying to take doxygen-like markdown from one project and use that language's compiler to spit out LaTeX, then consume that LaTeX in another related but different project, so there's a lot of "slicing and dicing" to tease apart the documentation and reconstruct it with the presentation required for this document. So the LaTeX is all auto-generated and whilst I can tweak the generation of it, I can't assume there's always a space after the `\@` (it could be a newline character instead).